# CDN serving chunk files

Tags: webpack

I have an angular 2 app and I am using WebPack for bundling. WebPack generates chunk files which are dynamically added to the webpage when it is loaded:

I want these chunk files to be located on a CDN server. I tried the publicPath property but the path is added everywhere except to the chunk file. Here is my configuration am I missing something?

```
 output: { path: helpers.root('dist'), 
 publicPath: 'https://my-cdn.net/', 
 filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js', 
 sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map', 
 chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js' }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Hi @FelixG what I am currently doing is manually including the chunk files with the CDN path in front inside the index.html. This seems to prevent the local chunk files to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine now, the public path is included everywhere. Make sure to include it in webpack.prod.js